# Netty loses udp packets at the beginning of the communication

Tags: udp, server, netty

I have a strange problem with Netty 4.0.27. I'm building a system which have to receive large number of incoming udp packet (all packet is 28 bytes long) and save them to a file. I implemented it and I also developed a simulator which send packets to the server.
I experienced that Netty server has a huge packet loss at the beginning of the communication, but after few thousand packet, the server received all packets successfully. Unfortunately, I can't afford this amount of packet loss (for example it loses 5-6 percent of first 200k packet).

I think, Netty adapts to high traffic, but I found nothing in the documentation. I also tried to use ChannelOption's SO_RCVBUF option but i had the same problem.

Comment: I think you will need to supply some code to get an answer on this.

Comment: I roughly guess it might take a while for JVM to warm up your application.

Comment: I agree with trustin here... most likely this because of warmup and optimization that take place at first.